# how to add columns across different Excel Documents?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 different Excel Documents and both has a column (say,A). I want to SUM the contents of column A from both the Excel Documents. how do I do that?

i know, if the content were distributed among two sheets in a single doc, the way to sum it up.

I have >100 docs. Any batch script will also be helpful.

thanks.

Comment: I think you will need `VBA` for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [consolidate data](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/consolidate-data-in-multiple-worksheets-HP010095249.aspx) to do this.

On the Data tab, in the Data Tools group, click Consolidate.

Choose the sum function, and select the books you want to reference with ranges and click "Add." They will look like

```
test1.xlsx!Sheet1$A$1:A$5, test2.xlsx!Sheet1$A$1:A$5, test3.xlsx!Sheet1$A$1:A$5
```

if you're summing A1 - A5 on each sheet.